# How to parse html by part of a class name with JSOUP?

Tags: html-parsing, jsoup

I'm trying to get a piece of html, something like:

```
<tr class="myclass-1234" rel="5678">
    <td class="lst top">foo 1</td>
    <td class="lst top">foo 2</td>
    <td class="lst top">foo-5678</td>
    <td class="lst top nw" style="text-align:right;">
        <span class="nw">1.00</span> foo
    </td>
    <td class="top">01.05.2015</td>
</tr>
```

I'm completely new to JSOUP, and first what came to mind is to get it by the class name but, the thing is that number 1234 is dynamically generated. Is there a way to get it by part of the class name or there is better approach?

Comment: What exactly does your HTML look like? JSoup expects a complete HTML or a Body fragment to be parsed.

Comment: @swinkler It's a pretty huge page, I couldn't show it here. It's standard, static html page, It contains multiple fragments identical to the one I showed above but with different class names(numbers are automatically generated) and with different valuable information of-course. What I'm trying to do is to extract all that information,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming a simple html containing two tr, but only one tr has the class you mentioned, this code shows how to get the tr using CSS selector:

CSS selector `tr[class^=myclass]` explained:

Select all elements of type "tr" with a `class` attribute that starts (^) with `myclass`:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class Example {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String html = "<html><body><table><tr class=\"myclass-1234\" rel=\"5678\">"
      + "<td class=\"lst top\">foo 1</td>"
      + "<td class=\"lst top\">foo 2</td>"
      + "<td class=\"lst top\">foo-5678</td>"
      + "<td class=\"lst top nw\" style=\"text-align:right;\">"
      + "<span class=\"nw\">1.00</span> foo"
      + "</td>"
      + "<td class=\"top\">01.05.2015</td>"
      + "</tr><tr><td>Not to be selected</td></tr></table></body></html>";

    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
    Elements selectAllTr = doc.select("tr");
    // Should be 2
    System.out.println("tr elements in html: " + selectAllTr.size());

    Elements trWithStartingClassMyClass = doc.select("tr[class^=myclass]");
    // Should be 1
    System.out.println("tr elements with class \"myclass*\" in html: " + trWithStartingClassMyClass.size());
    System.out.println(trWithStartingClassMyClass);

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
doc.select("tr[class~=myclass.*]");
```

Will select any div where the  content of the`class` attribute starts with `myclass`.

Comment: For my case it will be `tr`, Anyway thank you for laconic answer with laconic solution.